# Are all $R^2=T$ maps on a vector space an operator?

Tags: linear-algebra

A definition given in a book for square root of an operator is as follows :
"An operator $R$ is called a square root of an operator $T$ if $R^2=T$" ,
but I wonder does there exist other maps that map from same vector space to same vector space and obeys $R^2=T,$ yet is not a linear map . (Assuming a finite dimensional vector space)

Comment: Note that authors in many contexts will define "operator" to mean a linear mapping, in part because the topic being treated only involves linear maps.  With a little thought I'm sure you can come up with an example of a nonlinear mapping $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ that is a "square root" of the identity map (i.e. $f$ is its own inverse).

Answer (score 0):

Any non-linear involution, that is, a function which is self-inverse, would be a fitting example, since the identity is linear and the square of an involution is the identity.

Consider the function $R:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ with
$$R(x)=\begin{cases}\frac1x&x\neq0,\\0&x=0.\end{cases}$$
It's an involution of the real numbers, so its square is the identity, which is linear. This example can also be used for other fields.

Another, simpler example, which works for all non-trivial vector spaces $V$: let $0\neq a\in V$. Then $R:V\to V,x\mapsto a-x$ is a non-linear involution, since $R(R(x))=a-(a-x)=x$.